# NSURLConnectDelegate call before applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: iphone, ios

When I Request something from Service , then , press then Home button.

Then, tap AppIcon enter the application.

Then, some fantasy things happen.

The NSURLConnectDelegate

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

is called before the applicationWillEnterForeground. Why this happen???

Comment: you can cancel connection when enter in background... you should use AFNetworking for good control with operations..

Comment: Now, I also think i should cancel the connection. But, I want to know, why the NSURLConnectionDelegate is called before the applicationWillEnterForeground?

Comment: you should check how the queue from uiapplication works in documents...

Comment: I had read the documents about running background.But, can find some usefull info about this.

Answer (score 0):

if NSUrLConnection is finished loading when you are in background an event for it is sent and added to an event queue. When you re enter the app willEnterForeground event added to the queue.

Now queue events are dispatched one by one. If you don't want your app to finish loading when you are at background, you can cancel the connection before entering background.

Comment: you mean that: When the app is suspend, the  mainRunLoop event queue add a connectionFinish Event? So, NSURLConnection can run in background when the app is Suspend status?

Comment: There is grace time(10 mis generally) for you app to complete the task at background. When the time limit exceeded you get a time out.

Comment: There is grace time(10 mis generally) for you app to complete the task at background.  Is there any Documents talking about this?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: search for beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Comment: But, I did not add any backgroundTask code. My app do not support backgroundTask.

Comment: I don't think you have support background task for it. Normally all application will have some time to do things at background. I mean your connection doesn't snap as soon as you go to background.

Comment: In apple's Documents, the RunLoop begin work after the the delegate(applicationWillEnterForeground). So, I don't think the reason you said is correct.

Comment: "Normally all application will have some time to do things at background." I have never seen the documents about this. I really interest in this. Can you give me a link about this document, Thanks very much.

Comment: After doing some research, When app enters background it stays there briefly(If you haven't implemented background task) before goes to a suspended state. App can do things in background mode but not in suspended. Hence I could only assume that your network connection didFinish before app entered suspended state.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But, I still can not understand why it happen.